# $.rails.allowActionが見つかりません。どのGemを入れたら良いでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.2.5、Ruby 2.3.4を使っています。
「nested_form_fields」というGemを入れたのですが、javascriptがエラーで動きません。
「Add new」ボタンをクリックすると、想定通りjavascriptで行が追加されます。ただし、「Delete」ボタンをクリックすると、javascriptで行が削除されず、サーバにリクエストが送られてしまい、画面が再表示されてしまいます。
javascriptのエラーを見てみると、下記部分で「Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'allowAction' of undefined」というエラーが発生しています。このエラーのせいで、javascriptが正常終了せず、リクエストがサーバに送られてしまっています。

```
if (!$.rails.allowAction($link)) {
    return false;
}
```

そもそも「$.rails」自体がundefinedとなっているので、それが問題だと思っています。どのように解決したらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`$.rails`は、[`jquery-rails`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)という gem で定義されるようです。

そのため、`Gemfile`に以下を追加し、

`gem 'jquery-rails'`

`application.js`に以下が記載されていれば、`$.rails`が定義されると思います。

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```